# How to integrate different layout managers to fit this?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I assume I have to use a GridLayout(1,2), and assign the first side a null, and the second a JTextArea.

For the left side though, I'm not exactly sure what to do. Maybe possibly a BoxLayout?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to put a `BorderLayout` in the LHS.

- Put the label in the `WEST`
- Put the text area (that should really be a text field) in the `CENTER` or `EAST`
- In the `SOUTH`, put a panel with a centered `FlowLayout` for the button.

It really depends on how you want the extra space assigned in the event that the user expands the GUI.  Is the GUI resizable?

Comment: No it isn't resizable, as it is setSize at (500,200). That's what I tried to do. Is setting the LHS to null workable?

Comment: *"Is setting the LHS to null workable?"* No, not really.  See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for more on the subject.  Why use a text area for 'pet type'?

Comment: I meant a JTextField. And JTextArea for the pet list on the right. I also heard JList is a good way to display a Vector (which is what is used in this program) but not sure if the best way to go about it. Thoughts?

Comment: *"I also heard JList is a good way to display a Vector"*  Amongst other things, yes.  It is a great component for displaying collections or ..lists.  Definitely more appropriate then using a `JTextArea` in the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a single [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) and be done with it.  There's a little bit of learning curve (though really, not much) and you will be able to do this sort of thing very easily, and without nesting layouts.

Comment: while Mig currently is my personal favourite as well, it probably isn't an option in this case: homework usually doesn't allow third party frameworks :-)

Comment: @kleopatra  Huh..  I did not notice the 'homework' tag when I answered ( not that it would have altered my reply ;).  But I'll give a +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: @kleopatra - ah yes - good point.  What *are* they teaching kids in school these days...?!?